# Does the order in which $N$ elements are distributed among $m$ groups affect the probability of achieving that distribution?

Tags: probability

For instance, let's consider the following problem:

> At a party, a clown is throwing $N$ sweets to $m$ kids, with $N,m>>1$
>   and $N>>m$. If it is equally probable that a thrown sweet is caught by
>   any kid (the clown is throwing the sweets in a perfectly random way),
>   which would be the probability that the kid number 1 catches $N_1$,
>   the kid number 2 catches $N_2$, and so on,
>   $P(n_1=N_1,n_2=N_2,...,n_m=N_m)$?

**My attempt**

I have supposed that the first kids catches his $N_1$ candies first, then the second kid catches his $N_2$ candies, and so on, so that:
$$P(N_1,N_2,...,N_m)=P(N_1)·P(N_2|N_1)·P(N_3|N_1,N_2)·...·P(N_m|N_1,N_2,...,N_{m-1})$$

Then, each $N_i$ would follow a binomial distribution $\text{Bin}(p,n)$, being the available number of candies and the probability different in each case:

$$N_1 \sim \text{Bin} (p=\frac{1}{m},N) $$
$$N_2 \sim \text{Bin} (p=\frac{1}{m-1},N-N_1) $$
$$...$$
$$N_m \sim \text{Bin} (p=\frac{1}{m-(m-1)},N-N_1-N_2-...-N_{m-1}) $$

---

However,

- Would it be my first supposition correct? That is, would they be all the possible orders in which the distribution $(n_1=N_1,n_2=N_2,...,n_m=N_m)$ can be achieved equally probable?
- Could (or should) the solution be approached in a different way?
- In general, does the order in which $N$ elements are distributed among $m$ groups affect the probability of achieving that distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation is a bit confusing, but I think you mean that:

$$P(N_1) = {N \choose N_1} (\frac1m)^{N_1} ({m-1 \over m})^{N - N_1}$$

and

$$P(N_2 \mid N_1) = {N - N_1 \choose N_2} ({1 \over m-1})^{N_2} ({m-2 \over m-1})^{N - N_1 - N_2}$$

The interesting thing is that when you multiply them you get a lot cancellation:

$${N \choose N_1} {N - N_1 \choose N_2} = {N! \over N_1! ~(N-N_1)!} {(N - N_1)! \over N_2! ~(N-N_1-N_2)!} \\= {N! \over N_1! ~N_2! ~(N-N_1-N_2)!} = {N \choose N_1, N_2, N-N_1-N_2}$$

where the last notation is a multinomial coefficient of dividing $N$ things into sets of sizes $N_1, N_2, N-N_1-N_2$.  Similarly the factor $(m-1)^{N-N_1}$ appears in the numerator of $P(N_1)$ and denominator of $P(N_2 \mid N_1)$.  So:

$$P(N_1) P(N_2 \mid N_1) = {N \choose N_1, N_2, N-N_1-N_2} (\frac1m)^{N_1+N_2} ({m-2\over m})^{N-N_1-N_2}$$

This continues through all $N_m$ in a similar pattern, and in fact we have:

$$P(N_1,N_2,\dots,N_m) = {N \choose N_1, N_2, \dots, N_m} (\frac1m)^N........(*)$$

So to answer your $3$ questions directly:

- Yes your chain reasoning works, and in fact you can permute the $m$ kids in the chain and it will still work.  There is enough cancellation that you will always end up with (*).
- Yes IMHO the problem should be approached by directly using (*), which is a generalization of the Binomial method.  Your method is just re-deriving / proving it.  :)
- I don't understand your 3rd question.  But whatever it's asking, I hope (*) answered it!

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Regarding the third question, what I meant was if the order in which each kid catches the candy affects the probability of getting the result $(n_1=N_1,n_2=N_2,...,n_m=N_m)$. That is, if the situation in which each kid catches his candies consecutively would be equivalent to the situation in which each kid catches his $N_i$ of candies in a non-consecutive way.

Comment: e.g., the first two tossed candies are caught by kid no. 7, the third tossed candy is caught by kid no. 16, the fourth, fifth and sixth tossed candies are caught by kid no. 2, etc.. And if all the possible orders in which each candy is caught are equivalent.

Comment: I don't know if I have made myself understood...

Comment: Re: your 3rd Q: You need to be consistent on whether you're counting combinations i.e. (multi)sets (order doesn't matter) or permutations i.e. sequences (order matters). Your original Binominal coeffs & my multinomial coeffs count combinations, so they inherently already included all possible sequences. e.g. ${5 \choose 2} = {5 \choose 2,3} = 10$ precisely because it already includes all 10 sequences of AABBB, ABABB, BABAB, etc. I suppose it's possible to re-write the answer w/ permutations, but that just complicates things and you'll see enough cancellation to end up equiv to (*) anyway.

Comment: In general, if the question asks about an event which doesnt care about ordering, it is better to answer with combinations. This is not 100% true, but is predominantly true in practice. The exceptions are probably (sorry!) cases where the probabilistic model itself is sequence-aware, e.g. if having thrown a candy to kid A, that kid now has a bigger or smaller prob to receive the next (or any future) candy. It's usually not OK to tackle such prob models with combinations because AABBB and BABAB cannot be treated the same. (Such models are usually VERY difficult even if you use permutations!)